# Mixing RAM brands

Tags: memory

I'm scheduled to install a server at a colo facility tomorrow, but I've hit a snag. ESXi doesn't like the fact that I have 12GB ram in my server (8 GB on one side of the CPU, 4 GB on the other). I currently have three [Crucial 4 GB ECC DDR3 1333 MHz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TGT7EE) sticks, and I'm planning on stopping by Fry's on the way to the colo facility so I can pick up another stick so that ESXi will install. The problem is, Fry's doesn't stock Crucial RAM. They do have a stick that I think is identical to my crucial one: [DDR3 4 GB 1333 MHz ECC REG Patriot PSD34G1333ERK](http://www.frys.com/product/5915524?site=sr:SEARCH:MAIN_RSLT_PG)

Will this be dangerous to use in my server? The specs on the RAM (ECC registered, 133 MHhz, ddr3, 4 GB) are the same, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

The brand should be irrelevant if the timings and so forth are the same. You should be fine. Usually RAM problems present within a few seconds of powering on the hardware.